# When rendering my mirrored object, why does a line appear down the middle?

Tags: rendering, mirror

As said in the title, rendering my helicopter thing has a line down the middle, where it mirrored. Will this be a problem when exporting, or better, is there a way to fix it?

[image: My helicopter]

You can see the line down the cockpit. Please help :(

Comment: Did you enable clipping in mirror modifier?

Comment: I didn't enable clipping, but that doesn't appear to fix my problem

Comment: @Denis I messed around, and it did fix it! Thanks!